# Solving java.lang.NullPointerException Error Given Input from a user passed onto objects

Tags: java, class, constructor, nullpointerexception

The goal of my program is simple, ask the user for a factorial multiplier. Pass that value as an integer to another class, use constructors (Objects to do so). Use a getter setter and factorial method, and eventually returning the resultant result to the main method to be printed. However, When i attempt to run the program i get the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I have tried changing the method types to void, in attempt to make only one method have a return (getter type). However, that caused more problems as it stated that the (*) could not be used in a void method. Any input would be much appreciated. Here are my classes :

Main Program

```
import java.io.*;
public class RecursionIntroRev {
  Numbers p = new Numbers();
  public void main (String [] args) throws IOException {  
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader  (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String input;
    while(true) {
      try{
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a 'n' value (Factorial Multiple you wish to use)");
        input = myInput.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
        p.setNum(n);

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter valid input!"); 
      }
      System.out.println("The Factorial value is " + p.getNum()); 
    }
  }  
}
```

Numbers class (Setter,getter, Factorial method)

```
import java.io.*;
public class Numbers {
  private int x;

  public void setNum(int n) throws IOException {
    x = n; // setter
  }

  public int Factorial(int x) {
     // factorial method...
    if(x > 1) {
      x = x *Factorial(x-1); 
    }
    return x;
  }

  public int getNum() {
    return x; //getter
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the term 'stacktrace'. Care to expand?

Comment: nah, this can't be your code, main is not static..

Comment: Main was originally static, but when it was I had a different error

Comment: Show us that other error, it was the real one. And also how you run this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `main` method `static`, which is required for a main method that's meant to be the entry point of a program. Then, since you want to use the variable `p` in `main`, `p` will also have to be declared `static`. Static scope is picky like that. Another option is to simply move that whole line, `Numbers p = new Numbers();` inside your `main` method, since you only ever use it inside there. It's typically a better practice to declare variables closest to the place where you use them anyway.

After doing that, your program will compile and run fine, though you'll find there's a logic error in it such that when you give it input, it'll print out whatever number was given instead of the factorial of that number. You'll discover how to fix that by looking into the behavior of the method you're calling on the `Numbers` object: `getNum()`.

Comment: Yeah making it static definitely works, however, the logic error I can't really fix. I can understand why it returns the inputted number since it isn't in the factorial method. However,i tried to print p.Factorial(x) instead, that still proceeds towards an error.

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I placed the print statement right after the method calling the numbers class, putting the variable 'n' inside the brackets.